# Angular 6, Rxjs 6, process login using HttpClient

Tags: observable, angular6, rxjs6

I've never thought of myself as dumb, but I may have to reevaluate that position. I am missing something really simple here, but I just can't figure it out.

In my `login` component I have code like:

```
if (this.authenticationService.login(user,password)) {
    // Navigate somewhere else now the user is logged in
} else {
    // Display an error message and leave the login screen in place
}
```

Naturally, this is expecting a boolean response to indicate the success or failure of the login.

In the AuthenticationService there is a login function. It then adds headers and builds the body before calling `http.put<any>`

So my `AuthenticationService.login: boolean`

makes the actual call to `http.put`. Obviously this doesn't get executed until the `subscribe()` call.

My question is that, as I see it, I have two options. One is to delay somehow the `return success;` until after the `.subscribe()` has processed or to return immediately an `Observable<boolean>` (changing the function prototype to indicate that) and then sending `observer.next(true)` when the `.subscribe()` is complete.

The problem is, in spite of reading documentation from all over the place, much of which is contradictory, I can't figure out how to achieve either of these ends. Please note that I am using Angular 6 and RxJS 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a solution, but I'm not convinced it's the best one, but it works.
Here is an abbreviated `AuthenticationService.login`.

```
login(params): Observable<boolean> {
    var result: boolean;
    return this.http.put<any>(url etc)
        .pipe(map(data => {
            // Process the data and saving the token
            result = true; // or false as appropriate
        }), map( data => result));
}
```

This achieves my objective of handling all the tokens, etc inside my service and of returning an `Observable<boolean>` to the login component.

If someone has a better solution, I'd love to hear it. It has the feel of a hack to me. It's not elegant.

I went to bed immediately after posting this answer and as soon as my head hit the pillow, the proper solution came to me. I have just implemented it and it works fine. It's so obvious I feel kind of ridiculous that it took me so long to realize it. The improved solution is below:

```
    login(params): Observable<boolean> {
    var result: boolean;
    return this.http.put<any>(url etc)
        .pipe(map(data => this.transformData(data)));
}

private transformData(data): boolean {
    // Process the data and store tokens etc
    return true; // or false as appropriate
}
```

All the examples show processing the mapping in a `{}` block that the obvious solution of just calling an old fashioned function just never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you return an observable from your service so your component can subscribe to it.

```
// indicate a loading action e.g. spinner     
this.authenticationService.login(user,password).subscribe(loggedin => if(loggedin) {... do something} else { do somethingelse...)
```

And your login function would probably look like this:

```
login(user, password):Observable<boolean>{
    return http.post(parameters).map(result => result.loggedin)
}
```

Comment: Ah, the penny is starting to drop, but I want to do other stuff like store the token in localstorage first. Can I .subscribe().map( and map the prior result to a boolean?